# Please help :Click Submit button from VB.NET (WEbBrowser)

Tags: vb.net

I 'm  developing a vb.net application. I have a webbrowser, and i need to fill some info on a webform and click submit button. All is ok  except the submit, nothing happens !!! Please help !

The html page :

```
 <p>
        <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Publicar" />

 </p>
```

My Code :

```
  Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
    If PAgina = 0 Then
        Dim document As HtmlDocument = WebBrowser1.Document
        Dim inputValue As HtmlElement = document.GetElementById("title")
        inputValue.SetAttribute("value", "sdf  fdd  fh fgh fgh fg hfg hf ghfgh fg fg f hf fgh ")

        inputValue = document.GetElementById("zone")
        inputValue.SetAttribute("value", "Logroño")

        inputValue = document.GetElementById("editor")
        inputValue.SetAttribute("value", "Logroño s dfs dfs fsdfsd fsddfg dfg df gdf gdf gd df sd sd fsd fsdfsdfsdsdfsdf sdsdf")


        inputValue = document.GetElementById("email")
        inputValue.SetAttribute("value", "dfgdgrankkk@gmail.com")


        WebBrowser1.AllowNavigation = True

        **Dim submitButton As HtmlElement = document.GetElementById("submit")
        submitButton.InvokeMember("submit")
        ' WebBrowser1.Document.Forms("post").InvokeMember("submit")**
        PAgina = 1
    End If
```

end  sub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
.InvokeMember("click")  ; // instead of "submit" ?
```

or try to add few seconds delay before submit.